# using manual hyphenating does not work

Tags: html, css

According to fiddle I have tried to using manual hyphenating, on my code I used (­) sign over "between" word but the answer gave no hyphen in output! What is my problem?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7hgqket/) is the Fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<p>word-spacing to zero to remove the space betwe&shy;en inline-block</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p{
background-color:lightblue;
text-align:justify;
word-break:break-all;
width:160px;
hyphens: manual;
```

}

Comment: Its the browser issue please check with the code which I provided

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to happen. Can you post an image on how you'd like it the look. `shy;` insert an *optional* hyphenation location that the browser only uses, if it need to break at the place, which it (most likely) doesn't in this case.

Comment: i like to figure between something such as betwe-en !
and creating hyphens in a line by using style sheet hyphens: manual ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SOFT HYPHEN character, which is what `&shy;` evaluates to, is an *optional* hyphen according to its Unicode definition, which is what applies in HTML. This means that it indicates a permissible hyphenation point. Nothing more, nothing less.

Your code uses `word-break: break-all;`, which allows any string to be broken directly, with no hyphenation indication, as needed to satisfy the formatting requirements. In this case, it may e.g. cause the word “remove” to be split to “r” and “emove”. Such settings should of course be used only for languages and notational systems that allow such breaking, not e.g. for the English language.

What matters here is that due to breaking words that badly, the browser will have no need to consider hyphenating “between” later on (depending on font as usual). So it simply ignores the optional hyphenation point.

If you remove the `word-break: break-all;` declaration, then, assuming Times New Roman (the common default font) is used, browsers indeed hyphenate “between” as “betwe-” and “en” as suggested (which is a grossly wrong hyphenation, but that’s not important right now). This takes place even without `hyphens: manual`, which tells the browser to apply *only* the manual hyphenation hints and is actually just the initial value and the common default value. Using `hyphens: auto` allows browsers to use hyphenation hints *and* apply their own hyphenation algorithms, if they have them.

Example (on request as per comment, but using a correct hyphenation hint in the word “between”):

```css
p{
font: 16px Times New Roman;
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: justify;
width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<p>word-spacing to zero to remove the space be&shy;tween inline-block</p>
```

Comment: please give an example that show using of hyphenate in (fiddle)!

Comment: i think using of (word-break:break-all); and sign (&#45;) after all the last words thats broken to new lines , can create acceptable paragraphs see http://jsfiddle.net/w7hgqket/8/

Comment: @KeivanSabil..., `&#45;` just stands for the common hyphen “-”. If you intend to hyphenate the text by hand *in a fixed manner*, it is much more reliable to do that with explicit `<br>` tags than with `word-break: break-all` (it just breaks everything). And it’s seriously inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

Try Some thing like this..

```
<p>word-spacing to zero to remove the space betwe &#45;en inline-block</p>
```

for any further please check this

```
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm
```